# How to change a single image with a single button...?

Tags: javascript, html, image, button

I am building an HTML document for a friend.  The idea is that his kid really likes cars and so he can go to this website and click on buttons on the site that will give him different images of cars.  I am trying to wire up a situation where on the page there will be 9 different car images each with a button underneath that he can click on that will change only the one image that he has clicked on.  I have been struggling to accomplish this and surfing Stack Overflow for solutions has made me even more confused.  I am hopeful someone can help.

Here is what I've already tried ...

HTML -

```
<div class="carsButton">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/344x220/?cars" width="100%" height="225">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" onClick="buttonClickThing()">Refresh Image</button>
                </div>
            <small class="text-muted">1</small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS -

```
function buttonClickThing () {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementsByClassName("carsButton", "carsImage").src = "https://source.unsplash.com/344x220/?cars" + d.getTime();

    console.log(' done ');

}
```

I put the 'done' console comment in so that I know the button is working properly.  I will see the 'done' come onto the console but the image doesn't change.  I am fairly certain that I am either formatting this wrong or wiring the image/button wrong.  I am hopeful the community here can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="carsButton">
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/344x220/?cars" width="100%" height="225">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" onclick="buttonClickThing(this)">Refresh Image</button>
            </div>
        <small class="text-muted">1</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function buttonClickThing(elem) {
   var d = new Date();

  elem.closest('.carsButton').querySelector('img').src = 
  "https://source.unsplash.com/344x220/?cars" + d.getTime()

  console.log(' done ');
}
```

Comment: This worked!!!  Thank you so much!!!  I will have to study your solution in order to understand it.  This has been extremely helpful and will make a small boy just starting school very happy!  My hope is to explain to him how the code works to get him interested in writing code himself.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. You can check the docs if you like [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the `<img>` element when calling `document.getElementBy....`.
Try with the following solution:

```js
function buttonClickThing () {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("carImg").src = "https://source.unsplash.com/344x220/?cars" + d.getTime();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carsButton">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/344x220/?cars" id="carImg" width="100%" height="225">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" onClick="buttonClickThing()">Refresh Image</button>
                </div>
            <small class="text-muted">1</small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  That works for one of the images but then when I try to use the same HTML / JS solution for the second image on the page it only refreshes the first image instead.  I am assuming that I have to wire up some unique identifiers for each image that I want to change but I felt like there was a way to do it with one simple JS command vs. having to individually wire up one button each for one HTML element...

Answer (score 0):

when you useElementByClassName it returns array of object. then you must select first object then you can change it's src attribute.
use this code:

```
<div>
    <img class="carsButton" src="https://source.unsplash.com/344x220/?cars" width="500" height="225">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" onClick="buttonClickThing()">Refresh Image</button>
                </div>
            <small class="text-muted">1</small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function buttonClickThing () {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementsByClassName("carsButton")[0].src = "https://source.unsplash.com/344x220/?cars" + d.getTime();

    console.log(' done ');

}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  I did not know that using getElementsByClassName would return an array.  I had a friend of mine mention that I needed to grab the 0th object of the array but I didn't know how.  This is very helpful to explain his idea.  I appreciate all the help and advice.